# How to remove advertisement flags in advertising packet in android?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, flags, ads

Hi everyone I am developing an android app that make BLE advertisement. I am actually doing this but I want to use all packet for my specific data. Now I can manipulate manufacturer specific data but cant remove advertisement flags. How can I do this. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I don't know but my only guess is try to see what happens if you set setConnectable to false.

Comment: which argument setConnectable false?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/AdvertiseSettings.Builder.html#setConnectable(boolean)

Comment: Thanks so much this is working. If you make an answer I will accept answer.

Comment: Mark the ✓ button as well on my post ;)

Comment: İt is okay it takes 1 minute between upvote and accept answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/AdvertiseSettings.Builder.html#setConnectable(boolean) and set it to false.